# Importing XML to Excel error data imported as text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import XML files to Excel.

It returns an error

> some data was imported as text

I have to press okay for the code to continue.

I tried to insert error handlers.

```vb
Sub Import()
    Dim XMLFileName As String
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim WB As Workbook

    XMLFileName = "D:\Reservation Statistics.xml"
    
    SavePath = "D:\Reservation Statistics.xlsx"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    
    WB.XmlImport Url:=XMLFileName, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    WB.SaveAs SavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

This is the error
[image]

For fixing the number stored as a text later I use this code.

```vb
Sub txttonum()

    Dim rngRange As Range
    Set rngRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")
    rngRange.Value = rngRange.Value * 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a Map before importing the file?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-xml-elements-to-cells-in-an-xml-map-ddb23edf-f5c5-4fbf-b736-b3bf977a0c53#__create_an_xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could ignore/hid the error by using Application.DisplayAlerts = False so the final code is

```
Sub Import1()
Dim XMLFileName As String
Dim SavePath As String
Dim WB As Workbook

XMLFileName = "D:\Reservation Statistics.xml"

SavePath = "D:\Reservation Statistics.xlsx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set WB = Workbooks.Add

WB.XmlImport Url:=XMLFileName, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

WB.SaveAs SavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub